# how to combine two select query in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT users.firstname from users
INNER JOIN user_ps
ON user_ps.user_id=users.id where user_id=23 group BY user_ps.user_id

SELECT SUM(best + better + good) from user_ps as total where user_id=23
```

Hi I'm new user I need help here how can you combine both in one query please help me out

Comment: Please add some sample data, and expected result.

Comment: hey its not query maker please show what u tried ?

Comment: user table   user_ps    
       
id firstname  id user_id best better good
15 a  1 14 200  55
20 b  2 23 233 56 65
23 c  3 23 5 56 23
25 d  4 23 566  45


I want first name from usertable and that exists in user_ps with user_id along with all sume of best better good

Comment: Try some sub query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
SELECT users.firstname, SUM(best + better + good) AS Total
FROM users INNER JOIN user_ps
ON user_ps.user_id=users.id 
WHERE user_id=23 
GROUP BY users.firstname;
```

Comment: No Ankit Actually its was saying to wait for 5 min ;)

Comment: Also sorry ankit I cant upvote as i dnt have 15 reputation point

Comment: No prob. ultimately ur problem is solved. That was bigger achievment for me... Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it using union

```
SELECT users.firstname from users
INNER JOIN user_ps
ON user_ps.user_id=users.id where user_id=23 group BY user_ps.user_id
UNION
SELECT SUM(best + better + good) from user_ps as total where user_id=23
```

Comment: Yes exactly the same bt it shows in one column i want seperate it